# Por que da esse valor "(1):(2)(3)"?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou fazendo um cronometro usando o Android Studio, no documento xml ao qual a classe java "chama"

Estou usando Chronometer  para fazer o cronometro

so que quando termino de fazer sempre ocorre esse problema (1):(2)(3), e quando mudo de codigo ocorre o mesmo problema a preview mostra (1):(2)(3).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode postar mais informações, código java, xml ?

Comment: Pois no caso esse "(1):(23)" é a identificação do cronometro no layout.

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta e, por fim, acesse a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para verificar vários artigos que te lhe ajudarão a entender melhor o site.

Comment: **Sempre** coloque seu código como texto não como imagem

Comment: quando peguei outros códigos para ver se era falha minha e descobri que a preview mostrava a mesma coisa, "(1):(23)" , era para mostrar 00:00 ou 00 e não (1):(23)

Answer (score -1):

Se seu problema for apenas mostrar o (1):(23), monte sua TextView de como no código abaixo.

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewCronometro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textSize="80dp" />
```